# Edittext Validation in android using textwatcher

Tags: android, validation, pattern-matching, textwatcher

In registration activity, i have tried several codes for validation of edittext but still my application closes unfortunately.

```
    public class RegisterActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private EditText eusername, eemail, emobile, epassword;
    private Button btnSubmit;
    Context context; Matcher matcher;
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String username, email, mobile, password;
     TextView textViewPasswordStrengthIndiactor;
    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "MY_URL";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        eusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_name);
        eemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        emobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_phone);
        epassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        //chb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbShowPwd);
        //chb.setOnClickListener(this);

    eusername.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           // textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    eemail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    emobile.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //textView.setText("Not Entered");
            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
        });
        epassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });}


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (username.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter UserName", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }  
            //else if (!matcher.matches()) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter valid UserName",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //}
            else if (mobile.length() < 10) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter 10 digit Mobile Number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            else if (email.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter Email ID",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            else if (!matcher.matches()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter valid Email ID",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            else if (password.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please retry another password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }       
            else{
                new CreateUser().execute();
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
            }



    class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {    
        boolean failure = false;    
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = eusername.getText().toString();
            String password = epassword.getText().toString();
            String email = eemail.getText().toString();
            String mobile = emobile.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                // Posting user data to script
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(REGISTER_URL,
                        "POST", params);

                // full json response
                Log.d("Register attempt", json.toString());

                // json success element
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Register Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);    
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
            return null;    
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, file_url,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            }    
        }    
    }    
}
```

i tried with if-elseif-if loop method goggled too and also pattern-matcher, but didn't get desired results.
Tasks in which i need guidance-
(i) I need to validate email id pattern,password length, phone number pattern.
(ii)onclick submit button, checks if all fields are filled and then execute asynctask else return toast to the respective empty field.
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add stack trace?

Comment: open logcat and copy logs

Comment: validation depends on your self logic and rest about email id there are various functions available if you search

Comment: @Hulk i already used methods but it closes my activity unexpectedly.

Comment: Ok check this crash in logcat. send logcat details

Comment: just a second username is your object of edittext. How you are calculating its length. Use username.gettext().length()

Answer (score 1):

Declare globally.

```
    String username,password,email,mobile;

     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    username = eusername.getText().toString();
    password = epassword.getText().toString();
    email = eemail.getText().toString();
    mobile = emobile.getText().toString();

     if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            eusername.setError("Please Enter username");//using toast is  your wish.
            eusername.requestFocus();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            epassword.setError("Please Enter password");
            epassword.requestFocus();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            eemail.setError("Please Enter email");
            eemail.requestFocus();
        }
       else{
           new CreateUser().execute();
         }
       }
```